# Force window height, javascript

Tags: javascript, window.open

I am trying to force a `window.open` height to 0px, is this possible?

the code I'm using is this:

```
 window.open('', 'Address','toolbar=no,location=yes,directories=no,status=no, menubar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=no,width=100,height=0,top=100,left='+left);
```

But it won't resize it to 0 pixels, so the address bar only is available?

Can you please help me.

Thanks

Comment: i dont think any browser will allow you to create a window with 0 in either dimension, what exactly do you want to do? a popup hidden from the user?

Comment: No i want it to only show the "Adress" bar, so people can copy the url from there :-)

Comment: Why would you want that?  I don’t think it is possible — by design: you don’t want a javascript pop-up that does all kinds of unsavoury stuff while not visible to the end user.

Comment: Then just put it into a read only input.

Comment: Can you give me an example Virus721?

Answer (score 1):

According to [the Mozilla documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.open), "the minimum required value is 100".